# What is the current recommended way to record audio in a non-expo ReactNative app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio-recording, voice-recording

I have searched npm for "react native audio record" and have not found anything that seems to be maintained, used a lot, and growing in usage.  So, how do we currently record audio in non-expo ReactNative apps?

I have used [react-native-audio-record](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-record?activeTab=readme), but it had a precipitous decline about a year ago in weekly downloads, and has remained low.  And, after recording, on iOS I cannot play any audio file until I restart my app.  This issue exists whether I use [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound) or [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) to try to play an audio file.

I tried [react-native-audio-recorder-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player) but after half a day of trying to follow the setup procedure, researching errors, etc., I gave up - I can't get my project to build for iOS with it.

How should I go about recording audio in a non-expo ReactNative app to be released for iOS and Android?  I'm looking for a maintained, mainstream solution.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-av
It works on both expo and native apps, plus it is actively maintained.

Comment: I'm using react-native-audio-recorder-player without any issues on both iOS and android, also the installation was very simple. Which kind of errors do you encounter? Also expo-av works flawlessly on bare react-native apps (you have to follow the "bare react native" steps tho). It would also be helpful if you share some code and the issues you encounter with it.